# Read GCP credentials from Vault in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-gcp

Instead of having the GCP credentials somewhere locally, we decided to use Vault to manage them.

The below code is supposed to do the magic. However, when running `terraform plan` I always receive an error:

```
Error: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

The code we are using is below:

```
# Requires env variables VAULT_ADDR and VAULT_TOKEN set.
provider "vault" {
  token_name = "terraform"
}

data "vault_generic_secret" "gcp_credentials" {
  path = "kv/terraform/gcp/credentials"
}

provider "google-beta" {
  credentials = data.vault_generic_secret.gcp_credentials.data_json
  project     = "mip-ppr"
}
```

Comment: I forget if the Terraform provider for Vault supports beyond the KV secrets engine, but I think you need the GCP secrets engine for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I also need to create a normal `google` provider.

Adding this solved my problem:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = data.vault_generic_secret.gcp_credentials.data_json
  project     = "mip-ppr"
}
```